# Displaying image from device storage in Ionic App

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have image file on device in Android/data/myApp folder called test.jpg. I want to display it in img tag. I've tried every possible path in src attribute but nothing works. I've also tried change src to ng-src or data-ng-src. Nothing works and I am getting desperate.

The image is visible in storage when I look through windows explorer but it doesn't in my app. If I use $cordovaFile.checkFile function, everything looks perfect in the result data. File exists, has nativeURL but still doesn't show in the view.

Anyone had this problem? I've read everything google has to offer in this topic, but still without any progress on this issue. Can someone show me some simple example how to retrive image in Ionic app from device storage? What path should look like? Maybe I have to add some permissions to my config.xml or andorid manifest? 
It's my first hybrid App. I don't have much experience in AngularJS/Cordova/Ionic.

I've really stuck. Please help.

Comment: Could you show some of your code? If you use `ng-src` in your `<img>` and have it link to a function that returns the `nativeURL` by the `$cordovaFile.checkFile()` then it should work just fine.

Comment: Maybe this helps you [file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

Comment: Take care about the [content security policy](http://content-security-policy.com/)

Comment: What code do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I guess I have to answer this question myself. Everything works fine now when I use nativeURL of the file as src. I've added **img-src: *;** to the content of **http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"** meta tag in index but it still didn't work. After 10th time restarting app suddenly everything was fine. I still don't know if this was problem with meta tag but it work now so I am happy.

If anyone want to see my config.xml, manifest or index just ask.

Comment: can you tell now why that problem was occuring? I am facing the same issue since long time. Also, it would help me if you can show your config.xml and index meta tags

Comment: Sorry but it was almost year ago and I don't work on that project anymore. I don't have source since I've changed job.